# Correct Response code for an api which gets the status of a job (a failed one)

Tags: api, http, https, httpresponse

I am writing a simple GET endpoint which gets the status of an async job. What is the right response code to return if the async job has failed?

I certainly think it shouldn't be 500 as that means that my request itself has failed, which is not the case. The job the endpoint in enquiring about has failed, but not the response itself.

What would be the most appropriate endpoint to use?

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would respond with 200, because the http response itself was successful (5XX errors are infra errors). However, within the returned data, I would signal that there was a problem of some kind while processing the request.

If the server were returning json, I would respond with something like

```
{
  "error": "There was a problem of some kind",
  "data": null
}
```

In client receiving the data, I would then check to see whether the error field was null before considering the received data valid.

Comment: Thanks! Also, can we throw an error code when the response code is 200, so that the client can determine that the their async has failed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by throw an error code, but you can certainly assign an error code to the error data in the payload above.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, if I have a problem with another process in my request, I answer 500, because, I really had a problem and I need to fix it immediately.

In terms of other error invalid data, authorization, etc, you need to check the 4XX codes.

You can check the HTTP codes on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status